# How to test interrupted POST handling

Tags: python, testing, apache2, integration-testing, mod-wsgi

I am trying to reproduce a bug that is introduced by interrupted multipart POST. Thus, I'd like to do something along the lines of

```
curl -F 'item_count=8' -A 'Agent/4.0' http://tld/post/uri
```

but interrupt the request when data are send.

Arbitrary Ctrl+C is obviously not optimal.

Any tools that support that (except manual low-level socket play)?

Answer (score 0):

Spawn a thread and kill it almost immediately from the parent?